# How to fix "Class neither has a main method, nor is it a servlet" error?

Tags: java, servlets

I get the following error when I try to run a Web Application's class written in Java with Struts:

> Class "Converter" neither has a main method, nor is it a servlet
>   specified in web.xml Class "chap4.Converter" does not have a main
>   method

This is the only class from the project (class is called Converter.java):

```
package chap4;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;


public class Converter extends BodyTagSupport{
    private String _to = "F"; // This will correspond to the to attribute of your custom tag. By def, the conversion is to Fahrenheit.

    public String getTo()
    {
        return _to;
    }

    public void setTo(String _to1)
    {
        _to = _to1;
    }

    public int doAfterBody()
    {
        try
        {
            ...
        }
        catch(Exception ignore){}

        return EVAL_PAGE; //tells servlet container to process rest of JSP page.
    }

    private double toFahrenheit(double c){
        return 32.0 + (c*1.8);
    }

    private double toKelvin(double c){
        return 273.0 + c;
    }
}
```

I also added this in a file called lab4-converter.TDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.1//EN" 
                        "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd">


<taglib>
<tlibversion>0.0</tlibversion>
<jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
<shortname>message</shortname>
<tag>
<name>
write
</name>
<tagclass>
chap4.Converter 
</tagclass>

<bodycontent>JSP</bodycontent>
<attribute>
<name>_to</name>
<required>false</required>
</attribute>
</tag>

</taglib>
```

And then I added this in web.xml:

```
<taglib>
<taglib-uri>/tags/lab4-converter</taglib-uri>
<taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lab4-converter.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: There are a couple of oddities in your question.  You said your TLD was named `lab4-converter.TDL` (note spelling and capitalization), but in your `web.xml` you refer to it as `lab4-converter.tld`.  Also, it looks like your TLD misspells the name of the `write` tag's `to` attribute (which should match the JavaBeans property name in the tag class).  If fixing one or both of those solves your problem, however, then your servlet container has really crappy diagnostic messages.

Comment: Does commenting out the taglib declaration in your `web.xml` make the problem go away?